# Why my question about Fantom is closed as not constructive?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

This is my question which is closed:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189078/fantom-programming-language

Before telling me that the answers would be subjective have a look at your questions and answers and see how many of them are subjective.

I can't understand how a question about maturity and perception of a new programming language can not be constructive?!

My question is not obviously about technical detail, it's about the overall view about the language.

Answer (score 6):

You ask three different questions in your post. Of these three questions, only one may be suitable for our Q&A format, but it is significantly lacking in details.

> Does it worth to learn Fantom?

No one here can objectively answer this. As mentioned in [our FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), questions about what languages to learn are off-topic. We can't tell you if learning something will be useful or valuable to you or not.

> Is it mature to be used in real projects?

This is potentially good, if you define "mature". The definition of "mature enough" for use in a project depends on what you're looking for. Mature enough for a one-off personal application is different than mature enough for automotive applications is different than mature enough for high-volume financial trading.

> What Java developers think about it?

This is a poll. Polls are specifically mentioned as "not constructive" - all answers are correct and there's no way to judge correctness. This is explicitly mentioned in the FAQ and in the reason for closure.

---

Keep in mind that closure early is a good thing. It allows for the question to be improved before low quality answers are given. This is not a permanent state for a question - if edits can be made to make the question suitable, it can be reopened (either by a moderator if flagged for review or by 5 members of the community). Once a question has answers (especially bad answers or answers that are invalidated by edits), it's harder to get the question reopened.

Comment: By real project I obviously mean something more than a personal project and that's the point. If you keep this three question together and ask them about a new language then they would create a context and would be more meaningful. I can't accept you argument about being subjective, most of other question-answers in this forum are subjective (unlike SO). And finally see comments under question, I have tried to ask for help to improve the question.

Comment: @JohnS There are a lot of "real projects". Someone making a "real project" for a nuclear reactor has a different standard of maturity than a "real project" for a desktop to-do list. In order for subjective to be OK, you need to fully define and narrow your context (without making it so narrow that it can only help you and not other people in a similar situation). If anyone can help you improve, then they may read this Meta post and make comments - posting on Meta asking for help is far more visible than comments.

Comment: Well if replacing 'real project' with something like 'more than indie project' would help I will do that. I have posted on meta too! But seriously it is a lot less subjective than lots of other highly upvoted Q/As. My question is simply about the progress that this language has made into the developer community which is not that much subjective and is not an unimportant question.

Comment: @JohnS That's still not specific enough. Describe your project, and more importantly the quality characteristics of that project that you are seeking. Do you need fast network performance? Or fast disk I/O? Or need to communicate over message queues? Perhaps Fantom isn't good at some key part of your project. Those specifics are required to even reconsider reopening the question.

Comment: I think the criteria for closing a subjective question is asker reputation and verbosity of question.

Comment: As I said I'm not asking about technical detail, I'm more interested in overall language progress.

Comment: Have a look at this question: [Is Scala ready for prime time?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/77373/is-scala-ready-for-prime-time) It is only more verbose and has 20 upvotes.

Comment: @JohnS I'm not entirely sure that's a perfect question, but it's not only more verbose. It asks specific questions about IDE support, continuous integration tools, maintainability, and availability of documentation. It also mentions a specific class of application (enterprise applications) that tend to share a number of characteristics (database interaction, large scale, concurrent users, security and authentication). The question you linked to is awfully broad, but it's still much more specific than "Is Scala mature enough?"

Comment: That wasn't 'mature enough', it was 'mature to be used in real projects'! I guess, as programmers, when we talk about maturity we are talking about IDE support, tools, maintainability, documentations, community, etc. and I'm not sure we need to repeat them every time. I think that question was just more verbose than my question.

Comment: @JohnS My point still stands: what real projects? Games? Enterprise applications? Financial management systems? Automotive? Nuclear reactor control systems? I don't like comparing questions to other questions because every question is different. But your question does not describe your requirements or use cases while the other question does.

Comment: My question was not about the language use cases, it was about its maturity (IDE support, tools, maintainability, documentations, community, etc.). The language use cases are implicit.

Comment: Anyway I will delete it, and ask it again in a better way.